# R function rows_upsert without NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I recently discovered "rows_upsert" in R's dplyr.  If dt1 and dt2 are tibbles, I want to bring in new rows and updated cells from dt2, but I don't want to overwrite a meaningful value from dt1 with an "NA" value from dt2 for a matching row. Ideas?

```
key<-c("a", "b", "c")
values<-c(1, 2, 3)
dt1<-as_tibble(cbind(key, values))

key2<-c("a", "b", "c", "d")
values2<-c(1, NA, 4, 5)
dt2<-as_tibble(cbind(key = key2, values=values2))

dt1
dt2
rows_upsert(dt1, dt2, by="key")
```

The goal:

| key | values |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 4 |
| d | 5 |

Comment: `rows_upsert(dt1, na.omit(dt2), by="key")`?

Comment: (also, NAs might occur in either tibble, and I'm hoping to grab the meaningful values in either, if present. rows_upsert does that in one direction, but overwrites NAs over data the other direction)

Comment: @RitchieSacramento - Thank you.  That works for my toy example, but in reality the data tables have ~30 columns... and I think na.omit will throw out rows in dt2 with any NAs anywhere, and thus throw out lots of good information, much of which might be "new" and worthy of "upserting" into dt1.  I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### There are several ways to do this:

```r
require(dplyr)

dt1 <- tibble(key = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  values = c(1, 2, 3))
dt2 <- tibble(key = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                  values = c(1, NA, 4, 5))

## Using dplyr::filter
rows_upsert(dt1, dt2 |> filter(!is.na(values)), by = "key")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   key   values
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 a          1
#> 2 b          2
#> 3 c          4
#> 4 d          5

## or as Ritchie has suggested in comments:
rows_upsert(dt1, na.omit(dt2), by = "key")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   key   values
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 a          1
#> 2 b          2
#> 3 c          4
#> 4 d          5

## or piping rows_upsert output into rows_patch:
rows_upsert(dt1, dt2, by = "key") |> rows_patch(dt1, by = "key")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   key   values
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 a          1
#> 2 b          2
#> 3 c          4
#> 4 d          5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Much appreciation.  That seems to do it.  This is a fantastic community.